# How can I get my code to compile errorfree despite an array that might not have been initialized

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am writing a code that provides several options to the user.  Option 1 prompts the user to enter a string of values and then converts the values to an array.  Option 2 generates a random array of values.  Option 3 displays the current array.

I want the code to display an error when the user chooses option 3 without having first created the array, which would thereby make the array empty, or not initialized.

This is what I've come up with so far, but the code still won't compile without first displaying a warning that the code contains errors.

```
case 3:
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrReferenceString.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arrReferenceString[i]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("You must first provide a Reference String");
    }
```

This is the error
[Run Anyway Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMrWZ.jpg)

If I compile the code despite the warning, it runs fine.  However, I don't want the user to get the warning every time.  What can I do to the code to get it to properly compile?

Comment: What complete, exact and precise warning are you talking about?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 8.2.  The warning is:
One or more projects were compiled with errors.
Application you are running may end unexpectedly.
Options given are:  Run Anyway or Cancel

Comment: That's a warning you get when trying to **run** code that doesn't even compile. And running code tht doesn't compile makes little sense. You have a **compilation error** Read that compilation error, and post it in your question. You shouldn't even think about running your code if you still have compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by moving the array out of the main method and making it a static array in the class.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: That's not the right solution, at all. The solution (I can only guess since you never posted the error nor the code causing it) is to initialize your variable before using it.